# Can't install anything in conda environment. CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine

Tags: python, conda, environment

I have set up a new environment on conda.

Once it was created, I disabled threading so that the performance of the software I would be using will be maximised using:

```
conda env config vars set OMP_NUM_THREADS=1
conda env config vars set NUMEXPR_MAX_THREADS=1
```

I then tried to install the software and got the error

```
CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to
download and install packages.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

I though this could be specific to the software.

To test this, I tried installing python with

```
conda install -c conda-forge python
```

I got the same error here

```
CondaSSLError: OpenSSL appears to be unavailable on this machine. OpenSSL is required to
download and install packages.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

It seems to be an issue with the environment, but I have set up other environments on this machine before and never had this issue.

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Does this help ? https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11795

Answer (score 4):

it seems to be a conda bug. I found this solution in [this github issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11795#issuecomment-1410677462)

> copy libcrypto-1_1-x64.* and libssl-1_1-x64.* from anaconda3>library>bin
> to ananconda3>dlls

all credit to [mdbabumiamssm](https://github.com/mdbabumiamssm)

Comment: This fixed my issue.  No reboot is required

Answer (score 2):

I have now resolved this!

If anyone else has the same issue, going back into the base environment and then using "conda install -n name_of_environment python" worked.